# Idiomatic way to fill an arbitrary sized vector without array resizing?

Tags: memory-management, rust, memory-pool

There are times you want to allocate data without knowing ahead of time how much data you need.

Mostly vectors are fine as-is, but there are times where it is more efficient to allocate a chain of memory chunks, creating new chunks as needed.

If you don't need to access them directly by index (only pop the last item for example), they can be kept as memory chunks. Otherwise once this is done a fixed size vector can be allocated and the data copied into it.

While this could be done in Rust with a `LinkedList` of `Vec` 's, is there a more idiomatic way to perform this task?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I would favor a `Vec<Vec<T>>` in this situation, which is similar to how the `std::deque` is implement under the covers in C++.

With a `Vec<Vec<T>>` where all inner `Vec<T>` have the same maximum size, and all but the first and last `Vec<T>` are full to the brim, you can have O(1) indexing *and* memory stability.

Of course, the pointer to the chunks will move around as the outer `Vec` reallocates and all, but a `memcpy` of 24 bytes is easy enough.

Comment: A `(Vec<Box<[T]>>, Vec<T>)` is probably better than a `Vec<Vec<T>>`, since there's little point having capacity for all the inner allocations, and the having the last `Vec` inline will make for faster push/pops. But that's a minor thing at most.

Comment: @Veedrac: the big difference between `Vec<T>` and `Box<[T]>` is that in the latter you need the *exact* number of elements, whereas you can grow the `Vec<T>` as you need until it gets its "max" number of elements (but reserve first, to avoid re-allocating).

Comment: That's why it's `(Vec<Box<[T]>>, Vec<T>)`, not just `Vec<Box<[T]>>`. You don't want to resize the values in the middle, since those are all full.

Comment: @Veedrac: Ah, I see now. Indeed easing the pop/push may be worth splitting the first and last elements. However note that in a `deque` (C++), you can pop/push from both ends, and doing so at minimal cost requires NOT having the move all the blocks each time you have fully popped a block from the front. In my case, it would mean leaving empty `Vec<T>` in `Vec<Vec<T>>` which is fine as you can have an index indicating the first and last non-empty ones.

Comment: `Vec<Vec<T>>` isn't sufficient for a deque since you need to insert backwards on the LHS too. I'm not entirely sure how C++ does this, but a `VecDeque<VecDeque<T>>` would work, albeit slightly inefficiently.

Comment: @Veedrac: C++ basically uses a `struct { first: usize, last: usize, Vec<Vec<T>>, }` with a hard-coded size for "complete" inner `Vec<T>`. You sometimes have to shuffle the inner `Vec` back or forth (when you reach the edge, or re-allocate), but their content stays stable in memory, and getting to index `i` is something like `let len_first = outer[first].len(); if i < len_first { outer[first][i] } else { outer[(i - len_first) % capacity + first][(i - len_first) / capacity] }`

Comment: That's not what I was referring to, which was how it dealt with prepends. Which is actually obvious given it's C++ - it just inserts them backwards and decrements a pointer. You can't do that with `Vec` in Rust, so you'd need to juggle memory more dangerously to get things to work nicely.

Comment: @Veedrac: Ah I see, indeed it might be a bit trickier than just a `Vec<T>` to handle both prepend and append.